# Keyboard shortcuts do not honor selected input source in some apps

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, ibus, xkb

I own a laptop with a French azerty keyboard, when I installed Ubuntu, I chose to use an azerty layout but otherwise setup the whole system in english.

I then tried to plug my external keyboard which is a qwerty keyboard. I tried adding an input source for English us intl.
When I switch to that input source typing normal text is correctly using the new layout however for at least 2 very critical apps (vscode and intellij idea), keyboard shortcuts are interpreted with the azerty layout. The keyboard shortcuts are correctly interpreted in chrome and firefox

I tried changing the order of my input sources in the gnome GUI but then the shortcuts are always in english !

Basically it seems that the shortcuts in intellij and vscode and some other apps are always only on the first layout and are not impacted by the layout changes.

It feels like there are different layers of input layout or different ways to listen to keystrokes for an app and the gnome input source switcher "forgets" to change one of the layer/methods...

Here is what my Region and Language section looks like:

[image]

Here is the Language Support dialog:

[image]

Content of `/etc/vconsole.conf` even though I think it is irrelevant

```
KEYMAP=fr
```

Content of `/etc/default/keyboard` (which looks correct to me)

```
XKBLAYOUT=fr,us
BACKSPACE=guess
XKBVARIANT=oss,intl
```

result of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

```
[('xkb', 'fr+oss'), ('xkb', 'us+intl')]
```

result of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources per-window`

```
false
```

where it gets a bit weird is `setxkbmap`

```
setxkbmap -query  -verbose 10                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     fr,us,us
variant:    oss,intl,
options:    compose:caps,grp:alt_caps_toggle,eurosign:e
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(azerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+fr(oss)+us(intl):2+us:3+inet(evdev)+group(alt_caps_toggle)+compose(caps)+eurosign(e)
geometry:   pc(pc104)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     fr,us,us
variant:    oss,intl,
options:    compose:caps,grp:alt_caps_toggle,eurosign:e
```

Notice that there is an extra `us` layout, I can't figure out where it comes from

`ibus-setup` (because I switched to ubuntu from mac and I really lack a good emoji picker and tried to use ibus, though I find the picker lacking)

[image]

[image]

[image]

just in case: `locale` says

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

so yes, I have my system display english texts, but use french number, date and currency formatting because I'm used to it.

I am reluctant to resort to solutions such as :

- disabling gnome keyboard layout daemon
- forcing a setxkbmap command in ~/.profile as that would mean it would be easy to create a diverging configuration between `.profile` and the various system/gnome files (for instance if I add a 3rd input source later through the GUI I would have to remember to go back and change the .profile)

I was unable to find any reference to `xkb` or `layout` in the entire `/etc/X11` subtree. I don't have a .xinitrc or .xinputrc in my home directory.

What is the correct way to get intellij and vscode to respect the layout currently selected in gnome ?

--edit--

for the vscode part this is not the same issue as https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23690
starting vscode with the `azerty` layout selected still yields `qwerty` shortcuts (where ctrl+A ends up closing the window)

--edit2--

The correct vscode issue for this problem is https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24166

Comment: This is a guess, but one idea is to switch the order of your layouts (drag and drop in Region & Language) so English becomes the first in the list.

Comment: I tried that but then the shortcuts are always in english ! basically it seems that the shortcuts in intellij and vscode are always only on the first layout and are not impacted by the layout changes. (I have updated my question accordingly)

Comment: Another thought: What if you uncheck "Use system keyboard layout" in `ibus-setup`?

Comment: [Bug #1226962](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1226962) may be related.

Comment: I checked the `Use system keyboard` while trying to fix this issue, I couldn't find any difference with and without. I'll look into the bug you mention, thx

Comment: a superficial read of the mentionned bug seems to point to a different issue : I use 2 latin compatible layouts, all the shortcuts do work but are always mapped to the first layout even when I use another layout. ctrl+c and ctrl+v do work just fine everywhere but ctrl+q and ctrl+a are swapped for example

Comment: Well, I think that bug applies to any differences compared to the mapping of the first layout in the list. It's most obvious for non-latin layouts, but - as you have noticed - French AZERTY is affected as well.